# Azure VHD performance vs BLOB

Tags: azure, blob, vhd

I have 2 containers in the same blob service. One contains a single VHD, the other a single test PDF.

Running a process in a VM to which the VHD is attached, I get the following numbers.

VHD read:

```
// VHD = e: drive, copy files
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"e:\various\14681.pdf", FileMode.Open))
using (var mstream = new MemoryStream())
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        mstream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
// 20MB file = 250ms, 250k file = <1ms
```

blockBlob.DownloadToStream:

```
//read blob 
//CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("14681.pdf");

using (var mstream = new MemoryStream())
{
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(mstream);
}

// 20MB file = 700-800ms, 250k file = 40ms
```

Why is there such a difference in the performance of these two processes

Comment: What is the `E:` drive: temp disk on the VM? Attached disk? And if attached disk: regular storage? Premium storage?

Comment: e:\ is the VHD, regular (standard) storage. the blob is in the same storage account, but a different container.

Comment: Not sure why you're seeing a difference, but it could be in how file I/O is implemented, along with how reading/caching is done with an attached disk. With blob download, you might be limited by block-by-block access (vs a tool that downloads content in parallel streams). Note: If the `e:` drive was the temp drive, it would be easily explainable, as it would be ephemeral in-chassis SSD, vs network-attached.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you access the storage blob you are going through the public internet (not even internally), so that adds latency and when you access the VHD you go through the Azure Backbone (the hypervisor does that for you).
I would speculate that this is the main reason.

Comment: How did you determine that? The OP says the code is run on the VM.

Comment: determine what? Azure VM's cannot talk to Azure storage directly, so they always talk using public internet @DavidMakogon

Comment: That's not true. Calls to Azure Storage (within the same region) are not routed through the Internet. Nor are there any egress charges associated with working with a blob from a VM.

Comment: so why is there a requirement to whitelist Azure Datacenter IP's if you want to talk to Azure Storage from Azure VM in that case? @DavidMakogon

Comment: I have no idea what you're referring to. There's no firewall on Azure storage. There's a firewall on SQL Database, true, but that's not the same thing. And You can IP-whitelist ports on a VM but, again, not the same thing.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty confident about what I'm talking. Just block connection to internet on a VM and try accessing Azure Storage @DavidMakogon

Comment: DNS is something different. If your storage name needs external DNS to resolve names, not the same thing. I'm telling you how azure storage routing works, not how I *think* it works.

Comment: Well, I can say the same

Comment: Ok. I'm done here. Believe what you want. I'm trying to help out, but you seem to have a pre-conceived notion stuck in your head. FYI - feel free to check my profile to see where I work. And what I work on. I'm not making stuff up.

Comment: I know that, but I've just recently encountered this same situation, where traffic to Azure Storage (located in the same region) was blocked due to NSG rules

Comment: Also, I have an email from Azure Support confirming that @DavidMakogon